# How do I nest async React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, composition

This is a massively simplified version a React Hook solution that I am stuck on...

```
export const useStepA = () => {
  const [stepA, setStepA] = useState();
  const getStepA = useCallback(async (stepAParam: string) => {
    setStepA({ stepBId: '1' });
  }, []);
  return { getStepA, stepA };
};
export const useStepB = () => {
  const [stepB, setStepB] = useState();
  const getStepB = useCallback(async (stepBParam: string) => {
    setStepB(stepBParam);
  }, []);
  return { getStepB, stepB };
};
export const useStepC = () => {
  const { getStepA, stepA } = useStepA();
  const { getStepB, stepB } = useStepB();
  const [stepC, setStepC] = useState();
  const getStepC = useCallback(
    async (stepAParam: string) => {
      /* ????? await? useEffect? magic?
      getStepA(stepAParam);
      getStepB(stepA.stepBId);
      */
      setStepC({stepA,stebB});
    },
    [getStepA, getStepB, stepA]
  );
  return { getStepC, stepC };
};
```

In the real world... StepB is dependent on StepA's data, both are fetch calls... StepC takes the contents of StepA and StepB and returns an amalgamation of them...

How I can write the stepC hook to process and wait, then process and wait, then process and return?

Comment: This is really not a good pattern to compose hooks with. Hooks are declaratively data-driven, but you're trying to write procedural code. You need to have dependencies implemented in `useEffect()` hooks rather than trying to await your dependencies.

Comment: I think you should use useEffect with [stepA,stepB,stepC] and build as one custom hook

Comment: In this case, stepA and stepB are totally viable and useful on their own... but rather than forcing the dev to integrate them if they used both, I thought a third hook that did it for them would be nice.

Comment: It might be better to only have the underlying fetching logic abstracted away and use that in both `useStepA`, `useStepB` as well as `useStepC` instead of having `useStepC` use those hooks. But it is hard to tell with these abstract examples.

Comment: That isn't a bad idea @trixn ... ultimately I put all the content from A and B into C... but I may be able to abstract it out and use those calls in the hooks.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't believe this is a very composable pattern to begin with, it is possible to make them work somewhat with a bit of effort if you're careful to make your initial values for `stepA` and `stepB` falsy:

```js
export const useStepC = () => {
  const { getStepA, stepA } = useStepA();
  const { getStepB, stepB } = useStepB();
  const [stepC, setStepC] = useState();

  const getStepC = useCallback((stepAParam: string) => {
    getStepA(stepAParam);
  }, [getStepA]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stepA) {
      getStepB(stepA.stepBId);
    }
  }, [stepA, getStepB]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stepA && stepB) {
      setStepC({stepA,stebB});
    }
  }, [stepA, stepB, setStepC])

  return { getStepC, stepC };
};
```

Problems will most likely occur when there are two concurrent promises pending caused by multiple calls to `getStepC()` in a short period, and because the way `useStepA()` and `useStepB()` are implemented, there is no way to resolve these inherent race conditions.

Comment: I'll give this a go and see what happens.  I can probably negate the concurrency with an if condition... but we'll see

Answer (score 1):

There is a useSWR hook what solve kind of these problems. [check this](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching#dependent)

Comment: add more details